# IVR development

Tags: hosting, voice, ivr

I need to build an IVR application (possibly 10 Phone lines). I am entirely new to this domain and am familiar with some concepts, Can someone please provide me with some links/advice on how I can go about building the IVR system?

Also, I need to know the exact process, whats involved, if I need to rent phone lines? etc., If I want to provide a hosted IVR service to my clients, what do I need.

any advice is much appreciated.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this programming related?

http://www.asterisk.org/applications/ivr